# Why my ggplot bars are on two separate grids?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

This is from [an online example on Hidden Markov Models](http://gradientdescending.com/hidden-markov-model-example-in-r-with-the-depmixs4-package/).
There are the codes

```
  library(ggplot2)
    library(gridExtra)
    library(reshape2)
   
 ggplot(hmm1$draws, aes(x = as.numeric(roll), y = state, fill = state, col = state)) +  
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", alpha = I(0.7))  +
      scale_fill_manual(values = mycols, name = "State:\nPerson that\nrolled the\ndice", labels = c("Alice", "Bob")) +
      scale_color_manual(values = mycols, name = "State:\nPerson that\nrolled the\ndice", labels = c("Alice", "Bob")) +
      theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank()) +
      labs(y = "Actual State")
```

They are supposed to produce this outcome below

[image]

But I get that the bars are "overlapping", being positioned on two separate lines

[image]

I do not know if this depends on coding (I have tried different options but nothing changed) or on some parameters set on my R. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide the data in order to reproduce the plot?

Comment: @SantiagoI.Hurtado Added the link, see edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have state represented as a number on the y axis for this to work properly under the current version of ggplot:

```r
ggplot(draws, aes(x = roll, y = as.numeric(as.factor(state)), 
                  fill = state, col = state)) + 
        geom_bar(stat = "identity", alpha = I(0.7)) + 
        scale_fill_manual(values = mycols, 
                          name = "State:\nPerson that\nrolled the\ndice", 
                          labels = c("Alice", "Bob")) +
        scale_color_manual(values = mycols, 
                           name = "State:\nPerson that\nrolled the\ndice", 
                           labels = c("Alice", "Bob")) +
        labs(y = "State") +
        theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

**Data**

```r
draws <- structure(list(roll = 1:100, state = c("alice", "alice", "alice", 
"alice", "alice", "alice", "alice", "alice", "alice", "bob", 
"bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "alice", "alice", 
"alice", "alice", "alice", "bob", "bob", "alice", "alice", "alice", 
"alice", "alice", "alice", "alice", "alice", "bob", "bob", "bob", 
"bob", "bob", "bob", "alice", "alice", "alice", "alice", "alice", 
"bob", "bob", "alice", "alice", "alice", "alice", "bob", "alice", 
"alice", "alice", "alice", "alice", "alice", "alice", "alice", 
"alice", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", 
"bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", 
"bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "alice", "alice", "alice", "alice", 
"bob", "alice", "alice", "alice", "alice", "bob", "bob", "bob", 
"bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob"), obs = c(8L, 
9L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 10L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 15L, 17L, 14L, 14L, 
12L, 11L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 10L, 14L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 
2L, 6L, 12L, 14L, 15L, 12L, 8L, 12L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 
14L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 15L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 
13L, 18L, 9L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 10L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 15L, 12L, 11L, 
12L, 12L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 16L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 
5L, 3L, 3L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 10L, 12L, 6L, 6L, 10L, 12L, 7L, 5L
), dice = c(5L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 8L, 10L, 11L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 10L, 12L, 
9L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 4L, 10L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 7L, 
3L, 9L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 12L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 10L, 5L, 10L, 6L, 
11L, 2L, 6L, 10L, 6L, 9L, 7L, 10L, 11L, 8L, 7L, 12L, 9L, 10L, 
5L, 8L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 11L, 9L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 12L, 
7L, 7L, 2L, 7L, 6L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 11L, 7L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -100L))
```